# Can't find the cause of user credential prompts in SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint, ssrs-2008

I have a SharePoint 2013 instance that runs our company intranet site.  This past weekend we moved our site to a new set of servers and we also set the site up use SSL (https).  We also put the site behind a Citrix NetScaler load balancer and it is running on two web front end servers. Since this move, some, but not the majority users are being asked for user credentials when the site comes up.  We have spent 2 days trying to figure this out and this is what we have determined:

1. Users can hit cancel or the x to close the credentials window, and the site loads fine.
2. This only happens for about 30% of all the users.
3. I am one of those users and I am Site Collection Admin and Farm Admin.
4. Once the user dismisses the credentials window, the user isn't prompted again during his/her current session.
5. I have found that if I sit on a certain page on the site and return the home page (say after 15 minutes or so), that I will get prompted again.
6. It appears as if this issue only relates to the home page.
7. We have applied the recommended fixes for the Loopback check issue as describe [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_foxhole/archive/2010/06/21/disableloopbackcheck-lets-do-it-the-right-way.aspx)
8. The home page does have a Page Viewer control that has a URL path that points to a SQL Server Report server.  Both are part of the same domain.  (Intranet site url is https://intranet.mycompany.com and the report server is https://[servername].mycompany.com)

We're looking for any information that could help us figure out why this is happening or where to look, as we have exhausted most options.

**UPDATE**

Since the problem seemed so intermittent, I thought it may be an issue only one of our web front end servers behind our load balancer.  So, yesterday, at 9 am I took Web Front End Server 1 out of the load balancer (leaving Web Front End Server 2) and let it run most of the day using only the one server and the issue went away.  At about 1 pm, I put Web Front End Server 2 back in the load balancer and removed Web Front End Server 1.  We will let this run a few more hours today
but so far we aren't seeing the issue either.  So, while I thought it was a problem with one of the servers, it now appears to be a problem with the Load Balancer when it has two servers to balance.

Comment: Are you not able to use the F12/Dev Tools within your browser of choice to locate the request that's causing the log in prompt? Each browser's respective version of Dev Tools has a 'Network' pane; if you keep it open while browsing your site, you can sort/filter by HTTP Status Code to find the offending request when it pops up.

Comment: Post it on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ to get more exposure to question.

Comment: I'm using Fiddler to view all the traffic.  It wouldn't be a request causing the prompt, but a response.  However, I'm not seeing a 401 response in the stack which is really confusing.